# Chrome and Safari deselecting text on mouseup

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

The problem I'm having is with Safari and Chrome. It appears there is a bug that causes the mouseup event to fire twice when you click on a text or input box. I want the text in the input box to be completely selected when the box gets the focus (regardless if it's tabbed into, clicked on, or given the focus through code). If you tab to the box or give it the focus through code it works perfectly. However, if you click on the box, the text is selected until you let go of the mouse button. Then the text is immediately deselected. Here is the code I am using:

```
    <h1>Slope Intercept Form</h1>
    <form>
        <p>Enter the beginning X and Y coordinates for your line.</p>
        <label for="x1">X1: </label>
        <input id="x1" type="text" name="x1" maxlength="6" size="5"
            onfocus="this.setSelectionRange(0,this.value.length)"
            onblur="message(this.name, this.value)">
        <label for="y1">Y1: </label>
        <input id="y1" type="text" name="y1" maxlength="6" size="5" 
            onfocus="this.setSelectionRange(0,this.value.length)"
            onblur="message(this.name, this.value)">
    </form>
```

Is there any way around this for Chrome and Safari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I created event listeners for the input boxes:

```
document.getElementById("x1").addEventListener("click", function() {document.getElementById("x1").select();});
document.getElementById("y1").addEventListener("click", function() {document.getElementById("y1").select();});
```

Now, when the input box is clicked, it is automatically selected. When the input box is tabbed into it is also automatically selected. Now I don't have to use the onFocus event to select the input box text. The onFocus event and onClick event were conflicting with each other in Safari and Chrome but not on Firefox, IE or Opera.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<input type="text" id="myText" value="Mickey" onclick="myFunction()">

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myText").select();
}
</script>
```

Here's a working demo using your code.  Notice there needs to be 2 different functions and two different getElementByID parameters:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJXLro

HTML:

```
<h1>Slope Intercept Form</h1>
    <form>
        <p>Enter the beginning X and Y coordinates for your line.</p>
        <label for="x1">X1: </label>
        <input id="x1" type="text" name="x1" maxlength="6" size="5" onclick="myFunction()">
        <label for="y1">Y1: </label>
        <input id="y1" type="text" name="y1" maxlength="6" size="5" onclick="myFunction2()">
    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("x1").select();
}

function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("y1").select();
}
</script>
```

As you may already know, it's a good idea to try to keep your HTML and JS as separated out from each other as possible (but that wasn't causing you the problem in your example).

Comment: Creating a separate function for every input field seems a bit inefficient considering I have many more input boxes for this form. I just listed the first two. Is there a way to get this same effect without having to create a separate function for each input field?

Comment: I've also noticed that using the onClick event with this method prevents the onFocus event from working. So, the input box only gets selected if you click in it, but if you tab to it then it won't get selected. If I just use the onFocus event then I get the same problem in Safari and Chrome where it deselects when you click on the box.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still looking for a better solution myself, but this is better than what I was doing before ;)