# Chrome is deselecting text when text copied from wikipedia, after calling setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, mouseevent, quill

I have quill editor,it shows some content copied from wikipedia in read only mode. I have to show a button above the selected text like this.[usecase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6csj6.png)

My approach.

```js
  componentDidMount = () => {
    let allEditor = document.getElementsByClassName("editor");
    for (let i = 0; i < allEditor.length; i++) {
      allEditor[i].addEventListener("mouseup", event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.handleSelection();
      });
    }
  };

  handleSelection = () => {
    this.setState({
      popup: true
    });
  };
```

if I remove setState, the selection stays there, but when I call setState,the selection disappears. After some debugging I found mouseup event fires after setState. This problem I am facing in chrome, for firefox it works fine.

Comment: Your approach seems wrong. You should **never** touch the real DOM in React.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems wrong. You should **never** touch the real DOM in React. Both the real DOM and Virtual DOM might get into conflict while you do the `setState`.

Whenever the state is changed, the whole component re-renders - which is the problem you're having right now. Instead, use an `onClick` or `onMouseUp` attribute so that you can attach the event handler, that's the right way and it's unobtrusive as well.

You have to listen to the synthetic events not real events.

Comment: I tried that approach too, but the result is same, I think this is a bug in chrome as asked in this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132937/chrome-and-safari-deselecting-text-on-mouseup

Comment: @Utkarsh Oh nice.